# copy images from local machine to server in asp.net C#

Tags: asp.net

I need to copy the images from C:/images folder to my web application folder which is running in the server.I used the following code which work well in local application but not work in server

```
   string sourcePath = @"D:\images";
   //string destinationPath = @"D:\a";
   string destinationPath = Server.MapPath("SMSImages") + "\\";
   if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(sourcePath))
   {
      string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath);
       foreach (string s in files)
        {

         fileName = Path.GetFileName(s);
         destFile = Path.Combine(destinationPath, fileName);
         File.Copy(s, destFile, true);

       }
```

how to copy

Comment: How is it not working?  Do you get any errors?  Or does the copy do nothing?

Answer (score 0):

Servers often have a lot of security limitations for the IIS user.

Check if the user under which you are running your asp.net process has authorization to access this path.

You can log the exceptions that are occurring in this code to see if it is causing an access violation.

The following code can help you check if code if you have access

```
 UserFileAccessRights rights = new UserFileAccessRights(sourcePath);
 if (rights.canWrite() && rights.canRead()) {
     lblLogMsg.Text = "R/W access";
 } else {
     if (rights.canWrite()) {
        lblLogMsg.Text = "Only Write access";
     } else if (rights.canRead()) {
         lblLogMsg.Text = "Only Read access";
     } else {
         lblLogMsg.Text = rights.ToString();
     }
 }
```

Comment: sure nunespascal, i check and inform, i want to know is there any other method

Comment: If you don't have access, the simplest solution would be to keep the images in a folder if your web directory. I am guessing that that is not an option, otherwise you wouldn't be trying to move the images by code in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't work because the program search a D:\ path in server not in local system.